# RewriteRule to allow one file in a directory and rewrite the rest

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a path /mydir which I want to rewrite to /mydir/store but I need to make sure that mydir/posts.php is still accessible in the same location while anything else in that directory is rewritten.

The rule for this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply exclude `posts.php` with a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/posts.php
RewriteRule ^mydir/(.*) /mydir/store/$1 [L]
```